# Including PHP-file with GET request

Tags: php, include

I need to include a file with GET request parameters in URL.
include("posts.php?p=".$post);
$post is 2. File posts.php exists.

Comment: include(posts.php?p=2): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u161493046/public_html/index.php on line 34

Comment: GET parameters are a way to achieve parameter passing remotely over the HTTP protocol. There's much better ways to achieve this within a PHP script (if I'm not mistaken the $post variable for example will be available to "posts.php" once its included anyway).

Comment: I want many things too... but If I don't express myself well, nobody will ever understand me...

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** Your question lacks some info. Are you having trouble with your project? Questions seeking for debug help *must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Meanwhile, consider taking the site's [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and stay on topic about [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Putting a filename in a GET request (or any request) is a bad idea security-wise. An attacker could utilize this to run their own code.